# Need Help calling a function when UI Picker value selected

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I am building a simple unit conversion app and want to have the user select what type conversion they want and have a function called so that when they input a number in one of the text boxes the conversion gets displayed in the other. I am using an NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the delegate method [`textFieldDidEndEditing:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing%3a) or register for UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification.